# what does echo - - - mean in shell command?

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following command:

```
echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/.../scan
```

How do I interpret this line of command? I couldn't find anything in Google because the characters in my line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "- - -"
```

print three dashes and two spaces to the screen

```
|
```

a pipe - take output of the left-hand command (echo) and feed it as input to the right-hand command (sudo).

```
sudo
```

run a specified command with `root` privileges

```
tee
```

the specified command, which will be run as the root user. Tee accepts input from its stdin (being fed the echo output via the pipe), and splits it into two outputs: the first goes to the screen, so you see `- - -` printed in your terminal, and also outputs to a specified file, `/sys/.../scan` in this case.

Since you haven't provided the full path to the `/sys` file, can't tell WHICH scan it is, but generally speaking, this command is probably telling the OS to rescan some hardware bus for changes (additions/removals).

Comment: Why sending "- - -" to .../scan?

Answer (score 1):

Check the first answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/192461/ubuntu-server-12-04-hotplug-sata-automount

From the link: `On Linux, you can tell the system to rescan an individual SATA port.So to rescan the SATA3 port`

Answer (score 1):

`echo "- - -"` simply outputs `- - -` to the standard output. The `tee` command (whose name comes from the plumbing T-pipe) splits the output two ways: once to its own standard output, and also to the specified file. `sudo` serves to run `tee` as the root user, in order to be able to write to the system file in `/sys`.

To recap, `echo "- - -" | sudo tee some_file` will:

1. write `- - -` to `some_file`, as the root user.
2. repeat the same output to standard output, presumably for logging/debugging purposes.

Comment: What does "- - -" mean to some_file?

Comment: @return0 That depends on the file. If it's a plain file, `- - -` will have no special meaning and the `echo` invocation will simply write 6 bytes (five bytes for `- - -` and one more for the newline) to the file. If it's a system file, as the path beginning with `/sys` suggests, the meaning depends on which system file it is. Triton's answer might provide a good clue.